A la hora de imprimir por pantalla los objetos se repiten
Estoy realizando un ejercicio en el que tengo que crear una agenda de contactos serializando objetos, he creado una clase Contacto donde tengo sus atributos y constructores. El problema que estoy teniendo con este ejercicio es que  después de haber introducido dos contactos y quiero mostrarlo por pantalla con el método mostrarContactos este se muestra repetido y no se exactamente porque.
En el metodo eliminarContacto estoy creando un nuevo archivo como temporal donde estoy escribiendo todos los nombre que no coinciden con el nombre que yo he escrito y luego borro el archivo original y renombre el temporal como el original. Pero lo que me hace es crear el archivo y no lo que supuestamente tiene que hacer
public class Agenda {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner (System.in);
        int opcion;
        String nombre;
        String apellido;
        File archivo=new File("agenda de contactos.dat");
        ArrayList<Contacto>agenda=new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println("BIENVENIDO A LA APLICACION AGENDA DE CONTACTOS DE MJE");
        do {
            menu();
            opcion=sc.nextInt();
            switch(opcion) {
            case 1:
                introducirContacto(archivo, agenda, sc);
                break;
            case 2:
                mostrarContacto(archivo, agenda);
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("Introducce el nombre del contacto que desee borrar");
                nombre=sc.nextLine();
                nombre=sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Introducce los apellidos contacto que desee borrar");
                apellido=sc.nextLine(); 
                eliminarContacto(archivo, agenda, nombre);
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("Aplicacion cerrada");
                break;
            
            }
            
        }while (opcion!=4);
    }
    private static void leer (File archivo, ArrayList<Contacto>agenda) {
        try {
            FileInputStream fis= new FileInputStream(archivo);
            ObjectInputStream ois=new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            while(fis.available()>0) {
                Contacto persona=(Contacto)ois.readObject();
                agenda.add(persona);
            }
            fis.close();
            ois.close();
        }catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnf) {
                cnf.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private static void escribir (File archivo, ArrayList<Contacto>agenda) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(archivo);
            ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream (fos);
            for (Contacto persona:agenda) {
                oos.writeObject(persona);
            }
            fos.close();
            oos.close();
            
        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private static void introducirContacto(File archivo, ArrayList<Contacto>agenda, Scanner sc) {
        String nombre="";
        String apellidos="";
        int numeroTel=0;
        try {
            leer(archivo, agenda);
            
            System.out.println("Introducce el nombre del nuevo contacto");
            nombre=sc.nextLine();
            nombre=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Introducce los apellidos del nuevo contacto");
            apellidos=sc.nextLine();    
            System.out.println("Introducce el numero de telefono del nuevo contacto");
            numeroTel=sc.nextInt();
            Contacto persona=new Contacto(nombre, apellidos, numeroTel);
            agenda.add(persona);
            escribir(archivo, agenda);
            System.out.println("Se ha introducido el contacto correctamente");
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("No se ha introducido correctamente los datos del contacto");
        }
    }
    
    private static void mostrarContacto(File archivo, ArrayList<Contacto>agenda) {
        
            for (Contacto persona : agenda) {
                System.out.println("Nombre: " + persona.getNombre() + " Apellidos: " + persona.getApellidos() + " Telefono: " + persona.getNumeroTel());
            }
        
        
    }
    
    
    private static void eliminarContacto(File archivo, ArrayList<Contacto>agenda, String nombre) {
        File original=archivo;
        File temporal = new File("agenda_de_contactos_temp.dat");
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(temporal);
            ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(original);
            ObjectInputStream ois=new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            
            while (fis.available()>0) {
                try {
                    Contacto persona=(Contacto)ois.readObject();
                    if (!persona.getNombre().equals(nombre)) {
                        oos.writeObject(persona);
                    }
                }catch(Exception e) {
                    
                }
            }
            
            original.delete();
            temporal.renameTo(original);

        }catch(Exception e) {
        }
    }
}


Para el caso de eliminar contacto, no entiendo qué quisiste hacer. Allí específicamente estás indicando en el método que estás creando un archivo nuevo. ¿Cuál es la idea de ese archivo nuevo? Pulsa en [edit] para agregar más aclaraciones.

Mostrar contacto muestra exactamente lo que hay.. si lo ves duplicado es porque esta dos veces.. te ijaste que no estuviera dos veces??? de paso, para que le pasas algo que no usas (el archivo???)

Se me habia olvidado quitar ese parametro, pero no consigo dar con la respuesta he estado un buen rato  mirando si es el de introducirContacto es el problema pero no lo consigo ver

Ya he solucionado el mostrar contacto solo habia que añadir en el metodo leer agenda.clear()

Aparecen repetidos porque el método de borrar no está funcionando. Si revisas en el case: 3, tienes dos veces: nombre=sc.nextLine(); y otra vez nombre=sc.nextLine();. Entonces, nombre se queda con el salto de línea, no con el dato que escribiste. Habiendo depurado el código poniendo puntos de interrupción y revisando el valor de los objetos te habrías dado cuenta del problema.
